# Filter differences in array

Tags: java, android, arrays, math, filter

I want to filter an array by calculating the differences. Here's the code:

```
public void compressData(List<Long> array){
    for(int i = 0; i <= array.size(); i++){
        if(Math.abs(array.get(i) - (array.get(i + 1))) >= 100){
            newArray.add(array.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Let's say I have an array of [1, 3, 5, 10]. I want the range between the numbers in array to be at least 5, so in this case the number 3 should be removed. So I want to compare array[i] with array[i + 1]

The code above doesn't work (I know it won't work actually, I think I'm just desperate) because `array.get(i - 1)` or `array.get(i + 1)` will give ArrayOutOfIndexException

Thank you in advance =)

Comment: Check out what an [`ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html) is, and then try to prevent it from occurring.

Comment: @Steven Jeuris I know that I'm accessing illegal number of array, because `array.get(i - 1)` will return array[-1] in the beginning of array and `array.get(i + 1)` will return array.size() + 1. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: For `[1, 3, 5, 10]` and a range `>=5` the answer will be `[1, 10]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

how about change your `for` line to :

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.size()-1; i++)
```

then you could use array.get(i+1)

Comment: It gives NullPointerException =O

Comment: null value check of  the input param (List<long> array) and the element of the 'array' should be done.

Comment: I still get NullPointerException. I think I missed the basic understanding, mind to explain null value check? Sorry if the question is noob =x

Comment: before you call array.size(), the array should not be null (array!=null) and before you do `Math.abs(array.get(i) - (array.get(i + 1))` the element i and i+1 should not be null. check them.

Comment: I've put `(array!=null)` before the loop and it returns NullPointerException at `newArray.add(array.get(i));`

Comment: I only declared `private List<Long> newArray;` in the beginning.

Comment: -> `private List<Long> newArray = new ArrayList<Long>();`

Comment: Darn, my bad about that. Sorry...Anyway, another error `IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 42, size is 42`

Comment: @StevenPongidin if you write the for line exactly same as the line in my answer. you won't get this exception. check the size()-1 and < (without '=')

Comment: Ok that works. Thank you very much, sir! Forgive me for all the stupid errors X_X

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
int diff = 100;
if (array.size() > 0) {
  newArray.add(array.get(0));    
}
int prev = array.get(0);
for(int i = 1; i < array.size(); i++){
        int cur = array.get(i);
        if(cur - prev) >= diff){
            newArray.add(cur);
            prev = cur;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are array and newArray not null?

Comment: Yes, `if (array.size() > 0) {` must be wider and enclose `prev` and `for`